# Prevent highlighting next line after comma in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, highlight

When I select a suggestion from the list of suggestions the `value` (here 80) is highlighted & selected automatically and as I continue to type in next line, the text is highlighted. How do I disable this behavior.
[image]

Comment: are you still in snippet-mode, press tab to get out of this mode and `80` should not be decorated any more

Comment: @rioV8 Pressing Tab instead of Enter does gets me out but i wanna know if behavior of Tab can be set for Enter key too or if this whole mode can simply disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following keybinding

```json
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && hasNextTabstop && inSnippetMode"
}
```

It copies the command executed when you press Tab.

Comment: After configuring this, I would need to press Enter twice to move to next line.

Comment: @RishabhSingh then use multi-command extension to construct a commandID combi that works for you

Comment: when I passing a prop while using a component in React, the value in `"` is also highlighted along with `"`. This only happens when I select the name of the prop from suggestions. I am trying to find a setting that stops this behavior. Not sure if commandId will help with that.

Comment: @RishabhSingh You can have multiple levels of snippets and completion items